# No puedo crear usuarios con Script de Bash

Tags: php, script, debian, cuenta-usuario

**La corrección del error se encuentra debajo del articulo.**

Error:

Estoy intentando hacer una pagina de registro en squirrelmail en una maquina virtual con debian10, he creado un .php (next.php) que recoge la información de el usuario y la contraseña que introduce el cliente que crea la cuenta, este php escribe el usuario y la contraseña en un .txt (passw.txt), ahora estoy intentando hacer un srcipt (script.sh) para que cree el usuario desde ese txt.

Este es el index de la pagina de registro:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Registro de Aritz</title>
<link href="estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="group">
  <form action="next.php" method="GET">
  <h2><em>Crear Nueva Cuenta</em></h2>
  
     <p>
      <label for="nombre">Nombre: <span></span></label>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-input" required/>   
     </p>
     <p>
      <label for="contrasena">Contraseña: <span></span></label>
      <input type="pass" name="contrasena" class="form-input" required/> 
 </p>
 <p>            
      <input class="form-btn"  type="submit" />
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es el next.php:

```js
<?php
$sobreescribir = "w+" ;
$handle = $file = fopen("passw.txt", $sobreescribir); 

foreach($_GET as $variable => $value) {


 fwrite($handle, $value);

 fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
header("Location: http://mail.sebastian.net/squirrelmail ");
exit
?>
```

El script de momento esta así:

```html
#!/bin/bash

user=$(head -n1 passw.txt)
pas=$(tail -n1 passw.txt)
sudo useradd -m $user -p $pas
```

Al ejecutarlo me da el siguiente error:

```html
root@debian10mail:/usr/share/squirrelmail/src# ./script.sh 
» incorrectobre de usuario «usuario
root@debian10mail:/usr/share/squirrelmail/src#
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si introduzco Hola (Nombre de usuario) y Prueba (Contraseña) en la pagina de registro el passw.txt queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Corrección de error para futuros casos:**

**Simplemente he cambiado un poco el script y he entrado a la terminal como sudo.**

**El script ha quedado así:**

```html
#!/bin/bash

USUARIOS=`cat passw.txt`


for LINEA in $USUARIOS
do 
 LOGIN=`echo $LINEA | cut -d: -f1`
 PASSWORD=`echo $LINEA | cut -d: -f2`

 useradd -m $LOGIN -p $PASSWORD

done
```

Comment: en next.php tienes esta linea: `frité($ande, "\r\n");`. Puede ser lo que te genera el error al añadir el salto de linea? muestra el archivo .txt que se genera, a ver si es correcto...

Comment: Buenas @Jakala he eliminado esas dos lineas, el código es de otra persona y no sabia que hacia eso hay, después de eliminar esas dos lineas todo sigue igual, te he añadido una captura del archivo de texto. Por otro lado, yo creo que lo que esta dando el error es el script que no recoge el nombre de usuario correctamente, pero al hacer un echo la variable funciona perfectamente, no se si me explico bien. Gracias.

Comment: puedes comentar el `sudo useradd..` y añadir una linea echo para ver el valor de las variables en el script???

Comment: Exacto, cuando introduzco un "echo $user" en el script, este me devuelve Hola, pero al ponerlo en el useradd deja de funcionar.

Comment: empieza a parecer mas un problema de ejecucion del comando usando SUDO dentro del script... el mensaje parece que hace referencia al usuario root, que es con el que tienes que ejecutar el comando... Cuando ejecutas el script, pones la contraseña de root?

Comment: Buenas @Jakala , lo acabo de arreglar. Gracias por todo.